# Using Ctrl-Shift to switch languages prevents from using other combinations, containing Ctrl-Shift in VcXsrv

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, vcxsrv

I am running `VcXsrv` with the following command

```
"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -xkblayout us,ru -xkboptions grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
```

in this case I am able to switch languages by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

combination but unable to send combinations like

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

in programs like PyCharm. If I run VcXsrv with

```
"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -xkblayout us,ru
```

then opposite happens: I can't switch languages, but can sent

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

combination.

Can I do both?

Comment: You can change the key sequence used for switching languages. While [this](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-8-how-switch-between-keyboard-input-languages) article is designed for Windows 8, if I remember correctly it's the same method for Windows 10.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 the question is about `vcxsrv`, inside Windows everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I've investigated it it was a long standing problem coming from X Window specification. IIRC, the specification states that switch must happen on key press (instead of key release which is what MS Windows always did). For this reason, X.Org maintainers refused to accept patches which fix this behavior. Probably *some* distributions applied the patches, but not the upstream.

As a workaround, use a combination which is not used in shortcuts. Shift+Caps, Alt+Caps, Both Shift, Both Ctrl, Both Alt should work. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45499/153754 for a list.